# Cannot access column in PostgreSQL table from Python model

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have defined a python class "Students", like this:

```
class Students(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = 'students'

    id_ = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = Column('nombre', Unicode(50))
    date_of_birth = Column(Date)
```

If I do `select * from students`, I can see all of these columns plus a few more, namely: `_created` and `_updated`.

I need to use the values stored in the columns `_created` and `_updated`.  So I try to access them like this:

```
#get student with id = 1
>>> s = dbs.query(Students).get(1)

# print its name
>>> print(s.name)
Richard

# try to print when it was created
>>> print (s._created)
AttributeError: 'Students' object has no attribute '_created'
```

Of course I get that message because the attribute `_created` is not defined in the model.

How can I access the value stored in the table `Students` even though it is not an attribute of the class `Student`?

Comment: And why would not you like to add these attributes to the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy needs the definition of each column it will access.  (There are ways to auto-discover by reflecting the database, but [explicit is better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).)  Add the column definitions to the model.  I'm assuming they're `DateTime`s.  You can use [`default=` and `onupdate=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html) to provide new values when a row is inserted or updated.

```
class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'student'

    id = Column('id_', Integer, primary_key=True)
    # other columns...
    created = Column('_created', DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated = Column('_updated', DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
```